# How to make PrintWriter overwrite old file

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where I need to print some data to a file. During debugging phase, I would like to overwrite the old textfile so that I don't have to delete the old file just to see the result of some changes that I've made in the code. Currently, the new output data is either added to the old data in the file, or the file doesn't change at all (also, why could this be?). The following is, in essence, the printing part of the code:

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] arg) {
     PrintWriter pw = null;
     try {
         pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Foo.txt", true));
     } catch (Exception e){}
     double abra = 5;
     double kadabra = 7;    
     pw.printf("%f %f \n", abra, kadabra);
     pw.close();
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Reimeus: Thanks! How silly of me :) Any idea why the new data might not have been appended?

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde It's strange that there's no append - are you sure the file is writable?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Upon further inspection of the file, I realize I might have been wrong in claiming there was no append. We can probably drop the issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Pass `false` to the `append` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) to overwrite the file:

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Foo.txt", false));
```

Passing `true` for the second parameter indicates that you want to append to the file; passing `false` means that you want to overwrite the file.

Comment: Thanks! How silly of me :) I'll accept your answer as soon as possible. Any idea why the new data might not have been appended?

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass second parameter **false**.

Also you can use other writer object instead of FileOutputStream as you are working with txt file. e.g

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Foo.txt", false));
```

or

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Foo.txt", false)));
```

while working with txt/docs files we should go for normal writer objects( `FileWriter` or `BufferedWriter`) and while working with binary file like .mp3 , image, pdf we should go for Streams ( `FileOutputStream` or `OutputStreamWriter` ).